# What's Difference between IsCallback and IsInAsyncPostBack

Tags: asp.net

I can't find any answer yet on google maybe it's a stupid question :)

Answer (score 0):

[**Page.IsCallBack**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.iscallback.aspx)

It is getting a value indicating whether the page request is the result of a call back. Its a special postback, so a round-trip always occurs; however, unlike the classic postback, the script callback doesn’t redraw the whole page. ViewState is not updated during a callback, it is for postback. IsPostBack is true when a method in the code behind posts a page

[**IsInAsyncPostBack**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback.aspx)

Gets a value that indicates whether the current postback is being executed in partial-rendering mode.

Comment: So, what makes those different in practice?